# Intuition behind One Class SVM (Scholkopf)

Tags: svm, unsupervised-learning, outlier

I am trying to understand the intuition behind the idea of finding a hyperplane that separates the training data from the origin in the feature space.

Why separation from origin with a hyperplane helps with outlier detection?

Is the origin the 0-vector in the feature space?

Any hint/assistance is appreciated.